# MFP 7.0 Java Adapter Build Error

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

I'm using MFP 7.0 Java based adapters and when I try to build, both through the CLI and Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Error: 
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:133: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:159: /wlp/dev does not exist.
```

I can build JavaScript based adapters just fine, this is only when trying to build Java adapters.

EDIT:

Here is the build error I get when using the MFP Studio plugin in Eclipse:

```
The installation directory is not valid. Check that the path points to a Liberty profile runtime environment (e.g. <path>/wlp).
```

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4304ebdc58a29dc94b08) for our `JavaSampleAdapterResource.java` implementation.

Comment: Can you give some more background to what you're doing, or provide an example project with an example Java adapter that triggers this error?

Comment: Also, I am assuming the error actually looks different for the Studio, because it's not using the CLI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "fix" this issue by reinstalling both the CLI and eclipse plugin.

Comment: Hi @Idan.  I just saw the exact same issue running 7.1 on a brand new Mars-based Studio and CLI install on Mac OS.  Was following the "First Hybrid Application" tutorial.  I've not tried reinstalling anything yet, so if you want me to gather logs or other collateral, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error for Mobile First version 7.1. 
After deep down debugging, I found out the root cause of it.

My mistake was, After the successful installation of MobileFirst 7.1, I moved my eclipse to new folder.

So whenever I tried to start the server or to deploy an adapter, I got this error 
**The installation directory is not valid. Check that the path points to a Liberty profile runtime environment (e.g. /wlp).**

I resolved the issue by following this steps :

- In server section, Click to add a new server
- Select WebSphere Application Server version x.x in IBM section.
- Click on configure runtime environments
- Select the first entry which says Mobile First Development Server
- Click On Edit
- Now In Path enter \plugins\com.worklight.worklight-artifacts_xxxx\liberty\wlp
- Click On Finish
- Now start your server.